# Sharepoint 2013 missing Manage Subscription

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I created a new report a couple days ago and when I went to schedule a subscription on the report the button was gone.

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qF2X.png)

I checked in the Central Administrator to see a service was stopped but it looks like its on.

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqVwB.png)

Does anyone have an idea what it could be? and it isn't permission based since I have used multiple accounts with full control security.